# Can't click on my nav bar because of background image

Tags: html, css

I'm new in HTML and CSS and I struggle with one thing. It is probably something simple but I can't figure out. I have a navbar containing a `ul`/`li` list, but I added an image and I want it behind that list. The problem is the image covers everything and I cant see my list only when I put the image on `opacity: 0.5` or 0.2.

"slika" is the ID for the background image container

```
* {
    background-color: #181818;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


nav {
    flex: 1.5;
}

.nav-links{
    display: inline;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.link {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 60px;
}

#slika {
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url("/img/nikeshoes.png");
    background-position:center;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 1500px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 10px;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Nike</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a class="link" href="index.html">Home</li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Shop</li>
            <li><a class="link" href="#">Email</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="slika"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide at least the minimum amount of HTML code so we can understand what you have, especially considering your problem is about the order of the elements. For instance, what kind of element is #slika ? What's its parent?

Comment: We need to see your HTML

Comment: If you want to put a background on the list, just apply it to the `<ul>` element. There's no reason to add a `<div>` under it and add a background to that. But you're probably going to want to remove the line that adds a background color to every element on the page, that's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply a negative `z-index` to the element which covers the navigation, i.e. add `z-index: -1;` to the CSS rule for `#slika`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you could use a negative z-index. Another option is to apply the background-image directly to the nav element.